# Get two types of number of rows with minimum lines

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query.

```
$sql = "SELECT customer FROM furniture WHERE id = :id AND category = :cat";
$stmt = $connectdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':cat'=>"1"));
$resulta = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rowcount = count($result);
```

This works perfectly. But I have a requirement to get the number of rows from `WHERE id = :id AND category = :cat`  as well as to get the number of rows from `WHERE category = :cat`. Is it possible to do both of them without having to write all those SELECT query lines twice?

Comment: what is `id` here? PK? If you need count of `category` field, you have to find it based on either `customer` or any other field in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional sum to get the 2 different counts something as

```
select 
sum(id = :id AND category = :cat) as count1,
sum(category = :cat) as count2
from furniture;
```

Later you just fetch the records and get the values of `count1` and `count2`

NOTE : If you just do row count it will always return 1 since its using the aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you write the query as:

```
select sum(id = :id) as numCatId, count(*) as numCat
from furniture
where cat = :cat;
```

Putting the condition in the `where` clause allows MySQL to use an index on `furniture(cat)` (or better yet `furniture(cat, id)`.  In general, it is a good idea to put common filtering conditions in the `where` clause.  This reduces the number of rows needed for processing the rest of the query.